# Unnest Query optimisation for singular record

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bigdata

I'm trying to optimise my query for when an internal customer only want to return one result *(and it's associated nested dataset). My aim is to reduce the query process size.

However, it appears to be the exact same value regardless of whether I'm querying for 1 record (with unnested 48,000 length array) or the whole dataset (10,000 records with unnest total 514,048,748 in total length of arrays)!

So my table results for one record query:

```sql
SELECT test_id, value
FROM <my_table_reference>, unnest(TimeSeries)timeseries
WHERE test_id= "T0003" and SignalName = "Distance";
```

looks like this:

| test_id | value |
| --- | --- |
| T0003 | 1.0 |
| T0003 | 2.0 |
| T0003 | 3.0 |
| T0003 | 4.0 |

(48000 rows)

This will continue until value (Distance) = 48000m (48000 rows) for 1 record: `WHERE == 'T0003`.

Total process was **3.84GB**

For whole table (~10,000 records):

```sql
SELECT test_id, value
FROM <my_table_reference>, unnest(TimeSeries)timeseries
WHERE SignalName = "Distance";
```

looks like this:

| test_id | value |
| --- | --- |
| T0001 | 1.0 |
| T0001 | 2.0 |
| T0001 | 3.0 |
| T0001 | 4.0 |

(514,048,748 rows)

Total process was **3.84GB**

Why are the process size the same for both queries and how can I optimise this for singular row extractions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because there is still need for a full table scan to find all the test IDs that are equal to the specified one.

It is not clear from your example which columns are part of the `timeseries` record. In case `test_id` is not one of them, I would suggest to cluster the table on the `test_id` column. By clustering, the data will be automatically organized according to the contents of the `test_id` column.

So, when you query with a filter on that column a full scan won't be needed to find all values.

Read more about clustered tables [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/clustered-tables).

Comment: I think you're right on the money here, I'll take a look into clustering. Thanks